# Is there a Maven plugin to generate AS3 classes from Java for BlazeDS?

Tags: maven-2, flex3, maven-plugin, blazeds

I'm looking for a maven plugin that would generate ActionScript3 classes from Java classes in order to access them by object remoting.
I've seen FlexMojo but it uses the GraniteDS generator which create some problems when it comes to map Enum objects (which can be fix through a workaround that is describe here : http://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Flexmojos+generated+AS3+model+with+Enum+support+using+BlazeDS?focusedCommentId=7634946&#comment-7634946 if you've googled your way here this might be useful) when working with BlazeDS.

Everything that I found so far are people who explain how to generate VO classes on flex side using Flash Builder 4, but this solution can not be used in an industrial development environment.

Comment: the main problem is that flex people think they can do everything from inside flex builder and adobe encourages this point of view by providing crappy tools. In my last flex project (granite) we used the flexmojo generator without problems for value objects (enums and collections worked fine), but I had to write my own generator for service events and many preprocessors for flex code, because mxmlc chokes on many code constructs that flex builder allows. You *can* use flex in an industrial development environment, as you put it, but there's usually a lot of hacking involved on the maven side

Comment: where did this end up?  I have the exact same issue -- a Java/Maven project and a ton of flex value objects to generate.  Not will to have Flex Builder be the place where that happens....

Comment: @HDave -- Finally we continue using the FlexMojo Plugin to generate the VO objects. When it comes to Enum objects we modifiy the read/writeExternal() methods to suite our needs.
I did not try the flex annotations system because it is too old and i'm affraid that when evolution comes into play i'll have some problems...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look also on http://flex-annotations.aixcept.net/examples/actionscript.html

Comment: Have you ever test it on Enum or Collection mapping with blazeDS ?

Comment: Tested in production with Collections without issues. Not with Enums.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this one, and while it is not a maven plug-in it could possibly be turned into one:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/

It was created by the guys who authored the book "Enterprise Development with Flex".  Look for the utility DTO2Fx.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You could host it in your own github maven repo if its not hosted, but what you need is cleartoolkit or DTO2x from Farrata Systems.